# iOS: Play Video Embedded in PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-viewer, embedded-video

We want to render a PDF which contains embedded video in our iOS app.

I found PSPDFKit (http://pspdfkit.com) gives the same functionalities. However it is the commercial framework.

Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Thanks.